# How short is the time for the manifestation of small amounts of energy to justify the existence of quantum fluctuations?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, vacuum

Uncertainty Principle allows the appearance of small amounts of energy from nothing, always on the condition that they disappear in a very short time.

Speaking in seconds, how brief should these phenomena be? Among other things, it serves to explain that, even for a very short time, it is possible to violate the energy conservation law.

I would like to know how long it actually takes (in seconds)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53802/what-is-delta-t-in-the-time-energy-uncertainty-principle

Comment: @PM2Ring Maybe is related to [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/395244/time-energy-uncertainty-relation-when-a-depends-explicitly-on-t), but seems that "time" here can't be translate in *seconds* as unit measure of time?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, the uncertainty principle does *not* allow you to violate the energy conservation law. In QM, energy is *always* conserved. But anyway, the time-energy uncertainty equation is $\Delta E \Delta t \ge \hbar / 2$. If we treat that as an equality and let $\Delta E$ = 1.022 MeV, the rest energy of an electron + positron pair, we get $\Delta t=3.22\times 10^{-22}$ seconds. But please don't take that calculation too seriously.